# How to determine if Git handles a file as binary or as text?

Tags: git

I know that Git somehow automatically detects if a file is binary or text and that `.gitattributes` can be used to set this manually if needed. But is there also a way to ask Git how it treats a file?

So let's say I have a Git repository with two files in it: An `ascii.dat` file containing plain-text and a `binary.dat` file containing random binary stuff. Git handles the first `.dat` file as text and the secondary file as binary. Now I want to write a Git web front end which has a viewer for text files and a special viewer for binary files (displaying a hex dump for example). Sure, I could implement my own text/binary check but it would be more useful if the viewer relies on the information how Git handles these files.

So how can I ask Git if it treats a file as text or binary?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

[`builtin_diff()`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/git/git.git/tree/diff.c?h=v2.30.0#n3403)<sup>1</sup> calls [`diff_filespec_is_binary()`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/git/git.git/tree/diff.c?h=v2.30.0#n3354) which calls [`buffer_is_binary()`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/git/git.git/tree/xdiff-interface.c?h=v2.30.0#n187) which checks for any occurrence of a zero byte (NUL “character”) in the first 8000 bytes (or the entire length if shorter).

I do not see that this “is it binary?” test is explicitly exposed in any command though.

`git merge-file` directly uses `buffer_is_binary()`, so you may be able to make use of it:

```
git merge-file /dev/null /dev/null file-to-test
```

It seems to produce the error message like `error: Cannot merge binary files: file-to-test` and yields an exit status of 255 when given a binary file. I am not sure I would want to rely on this behavior though.

Maybe `git diff --numstat` would be more reliable:

```
isBinary() {
    p=$(printf '%s\t-\t' -)
    t=$(git diff --no-index --numstat /dev/null "$1")
    case "$t" in "$p"*) return 0 ;; esac
    return 1
}
isBinary file-to-test && echo binary || echo not binary
```

For binary files, the `--numstat` output should start with `-` TAB `-` TAB, so we just test for that.

---

<sup>1</sup>
`builtin_diff()` has strings like `Binary files %s and %s differ` that should be familiar.

Comment: On cygwin (Windows), /dev/null does not exist. One has to use the magic SHA1 brought up by Seth. `git diff --numstat 4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904 HEAD -- "$1"`.

Comment: For those interested, the relevant code is first introduced in  https://github.com/git/git/commit/3ce8f08944e614813c7dfb212a88b7c4e3b443bc by Junio and implemeted as such to match GNU diff http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/diffutils.git/commit/src/io.c?id=8f4db99c5fe1b1bc0f9cb522e10289592acec0e0

Answer (score 40):

```
git grep -I --name-only --untracked -e . -- ascii.dat binary.dat ...
```

will return the names of files that git interprets as text files.

The trick here is in these two [git grep parameters](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-grep):

- `-I`: Don’t match the pattern in binary files.
- `-e .`: Regular expression match any character in the file

You can use wildcards e.g.

```
git grep -I --name-only --untracked -e . -- *.ps1
```

Comment: Works with later versions, but with git 1.7.5.4 this just gives _fatal: empty (sub)expression_.  Changing the regular expression to `-e .` works with this version (perhaps at the cost of misidentifying text files consisting solely of empty lines!).

Comment: Liked that simple way of testing the file a lot. Thanks!

Comment: I changed it to the `-e .` to be more compatible and added `--untracked` to work with a wider range of files.

Answer (score 21):

I don't like this answer, but you can parse the output of git-diff-tree to see if it is binary.  For example:

```
git diff-tree -p 4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904 HEAD -- MegaCli 
diff --git a/megaraid/MegaCli b/megaraid/MegaCli
new file mode 100755
index 0000000..7f0e997
Binary files /dev/null and b/megaraid/MegaCli differ
```

as opposed to:

```
git diff-tree -p 4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904 HEAD -- megamgr
diff --git a/megaraid/megamgr b/megaraid/megamgr
new file mode 100755
index 0000000..50fd8a1
--- /dev/null
+++ b/megaraid/megamgr
@@ -0,0 +1,78 @@
+#!/bin/sh
[…]
```

Oh, and BTW, 4b825d… is a magic SHA which represents the empty tree (it *is* the SHA for an empty tree, but git is specially aware of this magic).

Comment: Thank you, good sir.  I used `git diff-tree --numstat 4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904 HEAD` which has the `-   -  filename` format.

Comment: If you want a list of all the binary files in your repo, you can do `git diff --numstat 4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904 HEAD -- | grep "^-" | cut -f 3`

Comment: Seth please fix typo in last sentence, should be 4b82**5**d; SO will not let me submit a 1-character edit.

Answer (score 12):

```sh
# considered binary (or with bare CR) file
git ls-files --eol | grep -E '^(i/-text)'

# files that do not have any line-ending characters (including empty files) - unlikely that this is a true binary file ?
git ls-files --eol | grep -E '^(i/none)'

#                                                        via experimentation
#                                                      ------------------------
#    "-text"        binary (or with bare CR) file     : not    auto-normalized
#    "none"         text file without any EOL         : not    auto-normalized
#    "lf"           text file with LF                 : is     auto-normalized when gitattributes text=auto
#    "crlf"         text file with CRLF               : is     auto-normalized when gitattributes text=auto
#    "mixed"        text file with mixed line endings : is     auto-normalized when gitattributes text=auto
#                   (LF or CRLF, but not bare CR)
```

Source: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files#Documentation/git-ls-files.txt---eol
https://github.com/git/git/commit/a7630bd4274a0dff7cff8b92de3d3f064e321359

Oh by the way: be careful with setting the `.gitattributes` text attribute e.g. `*.abc  text`. Because in that case *all* files with `*.abc` will be normalized, even if they are binary (internal CRLF found in the binary would be normalized to LF). This is different from the auto behaviour.

Comment: This `git ls-files --eol` answer seems like it most directly answers the original poster's question, and is a huge upgrade from the accepted answer.  As mentioned in the docs, and confirmed via experimentation, this invocation gives information both about how git's internal analysis types the file and how the `.gitattributes` file types the file; having both can be extremely handy in narrowing down entries in `.gitattributes` only to those that are needed.

Comment: Unfortunally git ls-files does not work on bare repositories :/. So dunno how to determine this with a bare repository. (I used libgit2 for this which can do this, but I want to use git binary directly instead)

Answer (score 5):

@bonh gave a working answer in a comment

> git diff --numstat 4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904 HEAD -- | grep "^-" | cut -f 3

It shows all files which git interprets as binaries.

Answer (score 3):

> So how can I ask Git if it treats a file as text or binary?

Not only [`git check-attr --all`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-attr) is a good option, but with Git 2.40 (Q1 2023), "[`git check-attr`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/577bff3a81079ebaf278eb98e10453f65678c135/Documentation/git-check-attr.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-attr))</sup> learned to take an optional tree-ish to read the `.gitattributes` file from.

That means you can Git if it treats a file as text or binary, for any commit, not just the current HEAD!

```
git check-attr --all --source=@~2 -- myFile 

git check-attr --all --source=anotherBranch -- myFile
```

See [commit 47cfc9b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/47cfc9bd7d0add617cf6d928e96b7d207be614f1), [commit c847e8c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c847e8c228a7820f11ce66d82dc68cd2241af031) (14 Jan 2023) by [Karthik Nayak (`KarthikNayak`)](https://github.com/KarthikNayak).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 577bff3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/577bff3a81079ebaf278eb98e10453f65678c135), 23 Jan 2023)</sup>

> ### [`attr`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/47cfc9bd7d0add617cf6d928e96b7d207be614f1): add flag `--source` to work with tree-ish
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Karthik Nayak</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Toon Claes</sup>
> <sup>Co-authored-by: toon@iotcl.com</sup>

> The contents of the `.gitattributes` files may evolve over time, but "[`git check-attr`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/47cfc9bd7d0add617cf6d928e96b7d207be614f1/Documentation/git-check-attr.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-attr))</sup> always checks attributes against them in the working tree and/or in the index.
> It may be beneficial to optionally allow the users to check attributes taken from a commit other than HEAD against paths.
>
> Add a new flag `--source` which will allow users to check the attributes against a commit (actually any tree-ish would do).
>
> When the user uses this flag, we go through the stack of `.gitattributes` files but instead of checking the current working tree and/or in the index, we check the blobs from the provided tree-ish object.
> This allows the command to also be used in bare repositories.
>
> Since we use a tree-ish object, the user can pass "--source HEAD:subdirectory" and all the attributes will be looked up as if subdirectory was the root directory of the repository.
>
> We cannot simply use the `<rev>:<path>` syntax without the `--source` flag, similar to how it is used in [`git show`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/47cfc9bd7d0add617cf6d928e96b7d207be614f1/Documentation/git-show.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show))</sup> because any non-flag parameter before `--` is treated as an attribute and any parameter after `--` is treated as a pathname.
>
> The change involves creating a new function `read_attr_from_blob`, which given the path reads the blob for the path against the provided source and parses the attributes line by line.
> This function is plugged into `read_attr()` function wherein we go through the stack of attributes files.

`git check-attr` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/47cfc9bd7d0add617cf6d928e96b7d207be614f1/Documentation/git-check-attr.txt#L12-L13):

> `'git check-attr' [--source <tree-ish>] [-a | --all | <attr>...] [--] <pathname>...`
> `'git check-attr' --stdin [-z] [--source <tree-ish>] [-a | --all | <attr>...]`

`git check-attr` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/47cfc9bd7d0add617cf6d928e96b7d207be614f1/Documentation/git-check-attr.txt#L39-L43):

> ### `--source=<tree-ish>`
>
> Check attributes against the specified tree-ish.
>
> It is common to
> specify the source tree by naming a commit, branch or tag associated
> with it.

---

If you are using a [sparse checked out repository](https://github.blog/2020-01-17-bring-your-monorepo-down-to-size-with-sparse-checkout/#cloning-in-sparse-mode) though, make sure to use Git 2.43 (Q4 2023), which teaches "[`git check-attr`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/354356feffed7b3c72d62cd78fc7575efd5bad42/Documentation/git-check-attr.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-attr))</sup> work better with sparse-index.

See [commit f981587](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f9815878c16892aae7c5be11ac67200aef6e4ff6), [commit 4723ae1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4723ae1007f94cbb391c4fb5a042adccd038d9ae), [commit fd4faf7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fd4faf7a5d5d92ca3e50f5a6ee2f94676d83530b) (11 Aug 2023) by [Shuqi Liang (`none`)](https://github.com/none).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 354356f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/354356feffed7b3c72d62cd78fc7575efd5bad42), 29 Aug 2023)</sup>

> ### [`attr.c`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4723ae1007f94cbb391c4fb5a042adccd038d9ae): read attributes in a sparse directory
>
> <sup>Helped-by: Victoria Dye</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Shuqi Liang</sup>

> Before this patch, [`git check-attr`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/4723ae1007f94cbb391c4fb5a042adccd038d9ae/Documentation/git-check-attr.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-attr))</sup> was unable to read the attributes from a `.gitattributes` file within a sparse directory.
> The original comment was operating under the assumption that users are only interested in files or directories inside the cones.
> Therefore, in the original code, in the case of a cone-mode sparse-checkout, we didn't load the `.gitattributes` file.
>
> However, this behavior can lead to missing attributes for files inside sparse directories, causing inconsistencies in file handling.
>
> To resolve this, revise '`git check-attr`' to allow attribute reading for files in sparse directories from the corresponding `.gitattributes` files:
>
> 1.Utilize `path_in_cone_mode_sparse_checkout()` and `index_name_pos_sparse` to check if a path falls within a sparse directory.
>
> 2.If path is inside a sparse directory, employ the value of `index_name_pos_sparse()` to find the sparse directory containing path and path relative to sparse directory.
> Proceed to read attributes from the tree OID of the sparse directory using `read_attr_from_blob()`.
>
> 3.If path is not inside a sparse directory，ensure that attributes are fetched from the index blob with `read_blob_data_from_index()`.
>
> Change the test 'check-attr with pathspec outside sparse definition' to '`test_expect_success`' to reflect that the attributes inside a sparse directory can now be read.
> Ensure that the sparse index case works correctly for `git check-attr` to illustrate the successful handling of attributes within sparse directories.

---

Another way, with Git 2.44 (Q1 2024), the `builtin_objectmode` attribute is populated for each path without adding anything in `.gitattributes` files, which would be useful in magic pathspec, e.g., `":(attr:builtin_objectmode=100755)"` to limit to executables.

See [commit 2232a88](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2232a88ab6bfbe41faf73f85912937e20bf8b4ee) (16 Nov 2023) by [Joanna Wang (`joannajw`)](https://github.com/joannajw).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 3e85584](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3e8558438da8cecbc19d0dbcb786dbf9ca9462e1), 12 Jan 2024)</sup>

> ### [`attr`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2232a88ab6bfbe41faf73f85912937e20bf8b4ee): add builtin objectmode values support
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Joanna Wang</sup>

> Gives all paths builtin objectmode values based on the paths' modes (one of 100644, 100755, 120000, 040000, 160000).
> Users may use this feature to filter by file types.
> For example a pathspec such as '`:(attr:builtin_objectmode=160000)`' could filter for submodules without needing to have `builtin_objectmode=160000` to be set in `.gitattributes` for every submodule path.
>
> These values are also reflected in [`git check-attr`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/2232a88ab6bfbe41faf73f85912937e20bf8b4ee/Documentation/git-check-attr.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-attr))</sup> results.
> If the `git_attr_direction` is set to `GIT_ATTR_INDEX` or `GIT_ATTR_CHECKIN` and a path is not found in the index, the value will be unspecified.
>
> This patch also reserves the `builtin_*` attribute namespace for objectmode and any future builtin attributes.
> Any user defined attributes using this reserved namespace will result in a warning.
> This is a breaking change for any existing `builtin_*` attributes.
> Pathspecs with some `builtin_*` attribute name (excluding `builtin_objectmode)` will behave like any attribute where there are no user specified values.

`gitattributes` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/2232a88ab6bfbe41faf73f85912937e20bf8b4ee/Documentation/gitattributes.txt#L103-L117):

> ### RESERVED BUILTIN_* ATTRIBUTES
>
> `builtin_*` is a reserved namespace for builtin attribute values. Any
> user defined attributes under this namespace will be ignored and
> trigger a warning.
>
> #### `builtin_objectmode`
>
> This attribute is for filtering files by their file bit modes (40000,
> 120000, 160000, 100755, 100644). e.g. ':(attr:builtin_objectmode=160000)'.
> You may also check these values with `git check-attr builtin_objectmode -- <file>`.
> If the object is not in the index `git check-attr --cached` will return unspecified.

So you can do a `git check-attr $check_opts builtin_objectmode -- "$path"`

Comment: See also [commit 86cca75](https://github.com/git/git/commit/86cca7593e737c2dbd9909dd1fdb8a9b5758aad2) for a complete `attr.h` with git 2.40, Q1 2023.

Answer (score 2):

Use `git check-attr --all`.

This works regardless of if the file has been staged/committed or not.

Tested on git version 2.30.2.

Assuming you have this in `.gitattributes`.

```
package-lock.json binary
```

There is this output.

```
git check-attr --all package-lock.json 
package-lock.json: binary: set
package-lock.json: diff: unset
package-lock.json: merge: unset
package-lock.json: text: unset
```

For normal files, there is no output.

```
git check-attr --all package.json
```

Comment: On a file that's clearly binary (and detected by git as such), but is _not_ explicitly mentioned in `.gitattributes`, this also gives no output.

Answer (score 1):

At the risk of getting slapped for poor code quality, I'm listing a C utility, is_binary, built around the original buffer_is_binary() routine in the Git source. Please see internal comments for how to build and run.  Easily modifyable:

```
/***********************************************************
 * is_binary.c 
 *
 * Usage: is_binary <pathname>
 *   Returns a 1 if a binary; return a 0 if non-binary
 * 
 * Thanks to Git and Stackoverflow developers for helping with these routines:
 * - the buffer_is_binary() routine from the xdiff-interface.c module 
 *   in git source code.
 * - the read-a-filename-from-stdin route
 * - the read-a-file-into-memory (fill_buffer()) routine
 *
 * To build:
 *    % gcc is_binary.c -o is_binary
 *
 * To build debuggable (to push a few messages to stdout):
 *    % gcc -DDEBUG=1 ./is_binary.c -o is_binary
 *
 * BUGS:
 *  Doesn't work with piped input, like 
 *    % cat foo.tar | is_binary 
 *  Claims that zero input is binary. Actually, 
 *  what should it be?
 *
 * Revision 1.4
 *
 * Tue Sep 12 09:01:33 EDT 2017
***********************************************************/
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_PATH_LENGTH 200
#define FIRST_FEW_BYTES 8000

/* global, unfortunately */
char *source_blob_buffer;

/* From: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14002954/c-programming-how-to-read-the-whole-file-contents-into-a-buffer */

/* From: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563882/reading-a-file-name-from-piped-command */

/* From: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6119956/how-to-determine-if-git-handles-a-file-as-binary-or-as-text
*/

/* The key routine in this function is from libc: void *memchr(const void *s, int c, size_t n); */
/* Checks for any occurrence of a zero byte (NUL character) in the first 8000 bytes (or the entire length if shorter). */

int buffer_is_binary(const char *ptr, unsigned long size)
{
  if (FIRST_FEW_BYTES < size)
    size = FIRST_FEW_BYTES;
    /* printf("buff = %s.\n", ptr); */
  return !!memchr(ptr, 0, size);
}
int fill_buffer(FILE * file_object_pointer) {
  fseek(file_object_pointer, 0, SEEK_END);
  long fsize = ftell(file_object_pointer);
  fseek(file_object_pointer, 0, SEEK_SET);  //same as rewind(f);
  source_blob_buffer = malloc(fsize + 1);
  fread(source_blob_buffer, fsize, 1, file_object_pointer);
  fclose(file_object_pointer);
  source_blob_buffer[fsize] = 0;
  return (fsize + 1);
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  char pathname[MAX_PATH_LENGTH];
  FILE *file_object_pointer;

  if (argc == 1) {
    file_object_pointer = stdin;
  } else {
    strcpy(pathname,argv[1]);
#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("pathname=%s.\n", pathname); 
#endif 
    file_object_pointer = fopen (pathname, "rb");
    if (file_object_pointer == NULL) {
      printf ("I'm sorry, Dave, I can't do that--");
      printf ("open the file '%s', that is.\n", pathname);
      exit(3);
    }
  }
  if (!file_object_pointer) {
    printf("Not a file nor a pipe--sorry.\n");
    exit (4);
  }
  int fsize = fill_buffer(file_object_pointer);
  int result = buffer_is_binary(source_blob_buffer, fsize - 2);

#ifdef DEBUG
  if (result == 1) {
    printf ("%s %d\n", pathname, fsize - 1);
  }
  else {
    printf ("File '%s' is NON-BINARY; size is %d bytes.\n", pathname, fsize - 1); 
  }
#endif
  exit(result);
  /* easy check -- 'echo $?' after running */
}
```

Answer (score -12):

You can use command-line tool 'file' utility. On Windows it's included in git installation and normally located in in C:\Program Files\git\usr\bin folder

```
file --mime-encoding *
```

See more in [Get encoding of a file in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710374/get-encoding-of-a-file-in-windows)

Comment: I'm not the one who downvoted it, but it was downvoted no doubt because 'file' doesn't have anything to do with how git determines the file type. 'file' doesn't use git code, and git doesn't use the 'file' command. 'file', for instance, doesn't know anything about how the .gitattributes file helps git determine the file type.