# Correct way of reading /proc/pid/status

Tags: c++, linux, string, std, procfs

I read `/proc/<pid>/status` this way:

```
std::ifstream file(filename);
std::string line;
int numberOfLinesToRead = 4;
int linesRead = 0;

while (std::getline(file, line)) {
    // do stuff
    if (numberOfLinesToRead == ++linesRead) {
        break;
    }
}
```

I noticed that in rare cases `std::getline` hangs.

1. Why it happens? I was under impression that proc filesystem should be in somewhat consistent state and there should not be cases when newline is missing. My assumption was that `getline` returns `false` when EOF/error occurs.
2. What is the recommended, *safe* way to read `/proc/<pid>/status` ?

Comment: That is the "proper" way to ready any text file line by line. However if the process you're checking exits while you're reading the file, then the behavior might be different compared to reading other text files. And no [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) doesn't return a bool value, it returns the stream [which can be used in a boolean expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool).

Comment: As for your second question, there is really no safe way to read any file from `/proc/<some pid other than your own>/` because the other process might exit at any time. You probably need to use some other Linux-specific system call to get the status of the process, preferably in a direct system call with the kernel writing into a structure, rather than reading from a file using the standard C++ library.

Comment: I am surprised this should hang. I would suspect that' would be a bug maybe in the compiler, maybe in the `OS` because if another process removes a file from under you then that should cleanly generate an error in your file descriptor. And `/proc` is supposed to behave like any other file. Are you sure that that *exact* code causes his error?

Comment: @Galik yes, pretty sure. Attached by gdb, checked backtrace, continued execution, checked backtrace again. Here is it: https://gist.github.com/lstipakov/95e6091d53e8f779c14800e6309109c0

Comment: @lstipakov, what is the `strace` output of your program when it hangs?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a more sure path is to use fread into a large buffer.  The status file is small so allocate a local buffer and read the whole file.

[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14002954/c-programming-how-to-read-the-whole-file-contents-into-a-buffer)  look at the second answer for the simplest solution

This may still fail on the fopen or fread but a sensible error should be returned.

Answer (score -2):

[/proc is a virtual filesystem](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/lk/lk-7.html#ss7.5). That means reading from "files" in it is not the same as reading from normal filesystem.

If process exits the information about it is removed from /proc much faster than if it was real filesystem (dirty cache flushing delay involved here).

Bearing that in mind imagine that process exits before you get to read next line which wasn't buffered yet.

The solution is either to account for file loss since you may not need information about process which does not exists anymore or buffer the entire file and then only parse it.

EDIT: the hang in process should clearly be related to the fact that this is virtual filesystem. It does not behave exactly same way as real filesystem. Since this is specific fs type the issue could be in fs driver. The code you provide looks fine for normal file reading.

Comment: Alex, what syscalls are made to read file from proc in the example from question? Are there several syscalls there? It will be safer to do one-time huge-enough read of the whole file (all-or-nothing) ant then parse from user buffer.