# Is it correct to check if the number of items read is less than requested, rather than 0, in fread(3)?

Tags: c, file, io, fread

I'm a beginner to C. I was wondering if it correct to check if the return value of `fread(3)` (which is the number of items read) is less than the number requested, rather than just 0, to detect EOF. For example, say you have

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    unsigned char buffer[1024];

    while (fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), stdin) == sizeof(buffer))
    {
        printf("%s\n", "Not EOF yet");
    }

    printf("%s\n", "At EOF");

    return 0;
}
```

Is this correct? Should the check for `== sizeof(buffer)` be `!= 0` instead? Is `fread` allowed to partially fill the buffer?

The reason I ask: It appears that `read` may return less than `sizeof(buffer)`. Quoting the manpage:

> On  success,  the  number  of bytes read is returned (zero indicates end of file), and the file position is advanced by this number.  **It is not an error if this number is smaller than the number of
>          bytes requested;** this may happen for example because fewer bytes are actually available right now (maybe because we were close to end-of-file, or because we are reading from a pipe, or from a  ter-
>          minal), or because read() was interrupted by a signal.

However the same logic does not seem to apply to `fread` for some reason:

> On  success, fread() and fwrite() return the number of items read or written.  This number equals the number of bytes transferred only when size is 1.  **If an error occurs, or the end of the file is
>          reached, the return value is a short item count (or zero).**

So I would like confirmation that the check should indeed be `== sizeof(buffer)` and not `!= 0`.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: What you have is correct. Though when the condition is false it does not necessarily mean you have reached the end of file: "fread() does not distinguish between end-of-file and error, and callers must use feof(3) and ferror(3) to determine which occurred. ".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The part of the manual you qouted says:

> If an error occurs, or the end of the file is reached, the return
>   value is a short item count (or zero).

That means you can't use `!=0` to check if no error has occurred as `fread()` could return a short item count.

The man page of [`fread()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fread.3.html) also states:

> fread() does not distinguish between end-of-file and error, and
>   callers must use feof(3) and ferror(3) to determine which occurred.

So *if* the items count returned is less than requested, then you have to use `feof()` or `ferror()` to figure out which one occurred (If it's end-of-file then you can conclude that it's not an input error but the end of input on whatever stream you are reading from).