# Is there a git hook which can prevent binary check-ins

Tags: git

Does anyone out there know of a good git hook that will check for binaries on commit and throw an error?  I'm trying to prevent binaries from getting committed to my repository, but sometimes people make mistakes.

Thanks!

Comment: Please take a look at this gist & update as needed - https://gist.github.com/robertranjan/23570b820c534dd434ea2b409142c7f7

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know of an existing hook, but git already comes with a hook that checks for adding "non-ascii names", as a sample pre-commit hook.  This will likely already be in your existing git repositories as `.git/hooks/pre-commit.sample`.

Using that hook as a template and considering the answers to ["How to determine if Git handles a file as binary or as text?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6119956/1256452), you could do something like this (see ["git's semi-secret empty tree"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9765453/1256452) for where `EMPTY_TREE` comes from):

```
#! /bin/sh

stop_binaries=$(git config --get hooks.stop_binaries)

exec 1>&2

if [ "$stop_binaries" = true ]; then
    EMPTY_TREE=$(git hash-object -t tree /dev/null)
    # or: EMPTY_TREE=4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904
    if git diff --cached --numstat $EMPTY_TREE | grep -e '^-' >/dev/null; then
        echo Error: commit would add binary files:
        git diff --cached --numstat $EMPTY_TREE | grep -e '^-' | cut -f3-
        exit 1
    fi
fi
```

This uses `git diff --cached` to see what would be committed, comparing it all against an initial empty tree.  Note that it will reject commits with *already-existing* (but unchanged) binaries; to make it only reject *new or changed* binaries, add the `against=` logic from the non-ascii-names hook.  To reject only *new* binaries add the `--diff-filter=A` argument too.

Fancy this up with additional error-message text if you like.  You can reverse the test (instead of having to assert "stop binaries", make it default to stop and you have to set "allowbinaries" to add binary files), etc.  And of course you can allow specific directories full of binary files, or whatever, as well, by doing additional filtering on the diff-index output.

Comment: Sadly, using this with a ~100MB zip file crashed my 16GB Windows installation. So it seems this is not scalable.

Comment: @abergmeier: Odd.  Seems like a mere 100 MB should not be an issue there.  But on the other hand, I don't do Windows. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Shameless plug, but I [wrote a pre-receive hook](https://github.com/avar/pre-receive-reject-binaries) that does this in a lot smarter & configurable way after searching around and finding nothing that worked out of the box with stock Git without having to install some bigger Git management system.

Comment: renaming your `README` to `README.md` would be most useful!

Comment: Git hooks are great way to solve the problem but how do you distribute them to the users? Hooks aren’t transferred with a clone of a project, you must distribute these scripts some other way and then have your users copy them to their .git/hooksdirectory and make them executable.

Comment: SteveLorimer: Thanks for the tip. I wrote the docs in POD, but I just symlinked README.pod to the main script, hopefully it looks better now.

@Balualways: If you need to distribute them to your users you ship your repo with some script to install them in .git. It's a feature that they don't come with "git clone", because they impact normal Git commands, and can contain stuff that would e.g. wipe your FS. You don't want to worry about that when you clone some random project.

However there's no need to distribute this hook to your users. You just need to check it on push to your main repo.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar requirement for our Git repo.  We didn't want to allow very large or binary files to be checked in by accident since they can bloat the repo and are hard to remove from the history.  Frankly I'm surprised a hook like this isn't a requirement for all Git users.  We wanted ours to be on the client side so that the user would know right away that they had made a mistake.  We also wanted to allow the user to override the hook if they were sure that the file should be committed.

To test for binary files I just used Perl’s -B check. I chose to use the pre-commit hook. To override the hook we just print a reminder to tell the user to re-run the commit using ‘--no-verify’.

The max file size is arbitrary and set in the script.  You can set it to whatever is appropriate for your situation.

You will also notice that this only checks files that are being added (not modified) because we didn’t want the hook to become a nuisance every time a large or binary file was modified.  If you want to be more strict you can change the diff-filter to use ‘ACM’ (Added, Copied or Modified).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# The hook should exit with non-zero status after issuing an appropriate 
# message if it wants to stop the commit.

use strict; 
use warnings;

my $file;
my $MAX_SIZE = 100000; # Limit files to 100KB


# Only check binary and file size when files are added otherwise users
# get an error every time they modify they file.   This has the dissadvantage
# of not catching if a file grows too large after the initial commit
#
# Get list of added files only (i.e. new files)
my @new_file_list =  `git diff --cached --name-only --diff-filter=A`;
foreach $file (@new_file_list)
{
  chomp($file);

  # Check if file is binary
  if (-B $file)
  {
    print STDERR "WARNING: $file is binary.\n";
    print STDERR "Please check with repo owner before committing binary files.\n";
    print STDERR "To bypass this warning re-run your commit with the '--no-verify' option\n";
    exit 1;
  }

  # Check if file is very large
  if (-s $file > $MAX_SIZE)
  {
    print STDERR "WARNING: $file is greater than $MAX_SIZE bytes.\n";
    print STDERR "Please check with repo owner before committing very large files.\n";
    print STDERR "To bypass this warning re-run your commit with the '--no-verify' option\n";
    exit 1;
  }
}
```