# Avoid binaries in git commit

Tags: git, gerrit

I have git integrated with gerrit,
I am trying to stop committing binary files into git,

Here is what I tried:
I added `*.bin` in `.gitignore` file,
But that can be skipped using `-f` option while committing,

Can anyone suggest an alternative method?

Comment: Anything can be skipped or circumvented. If you don't want to commit binary files, just *don't*. `.gitignore` should be enough.

Answer (score 4):

If you really want to prevent any binary to make it to the repo managed by gerrit, you can add a pre-receive hook detecting binaries and rejecting the push: see "[Is there a git hook which can prevent binary check-ins](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20226941/6309)".

That way, you still can accidentally commit binaries, but you won't be able to push them to the remote repo.

Answer (score 1):

You really should try to use the [Git::Hooks](https://metacpan.org/release/Git-Hooks). We use here at work and it's pretty good to automate all kind of Gerrit verifications.