# How ro restrict the binary file such as (exe, dll, pdf, docx) in gitlab?

Tags: git, github, gitlab, gitignore

I do not want to make a large size of commit history in my repository. We know the `.exe` and other binary files have a large size. So I want to restrict those file while committing into the repository. I studied this [articles](https://robinwinslow.uk/2013/06/11/dont-ever-commit-binary-files-to-git/) but it has a way to delete the history but not what I want. I think this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20226132/is-there-a-git-hook-which-can-prevent-binary-check-ins) is related to what I want but I do not know how to use.

I have nearly 300 gitlab repositories. How to restrict the binary file committing in each and every repository? Does anybody know how to achieve it by server side instead of changing something in each and every repository?

I heard about `.gitignore` the file which is used to ignore these kinda files. But it also needs to do the changes in each and every project I think so.

Comment: use `*bin` `*.exe` (regex) to avoid these kind of situations

Comment: @ArpitSolanki Where and how to do this?

Comment: in your gitignore file. Just google that how to use regex in gitignore file

Comment: @ArpitSolanki Is `.gitignore` file need to add each and every project in gitlab?

Comment: @Arunkumar yes,I believe that  `.gitignore`  file can only be inside a particular repository and not for a set of repositories you will need to copy it to all 300 repos :(

Comment: @Hatik Is there no idea to do it automation?

Comment: @Arunkumar if you want it to be done automatically, I think you can only try writing a whole script on it. however I don't think that it will be easier than doing it manually IMO