# How to create hook on git to avoid binary files?

Tags: git, hook

How to get commit file extensions on the moment of pushing them to server and reject commits which have binaries on it like .jar, zips, pdf, png.... 
I m on proccess to clean our repositories and remove all jars , zips , bins, tars from repositories so I need some help on create a shell script to reject commits that have any of these files types.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you are asking for. Please review your post and try to explain the background behind your problem a bit more and state your question more clearly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a git hook which can prevent binary check-ins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20226132/is-there-a-git-hook-which-can-prevent-binary-check-ins)