# Why is Git assessing these Ruby files as binary?

Tags: git

I am walking through the [manual re-remerge](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Advanced-Merging/#_manual_remerge) documentation in the Git Book. When trying to do a `merge-file` on the three `.rb` files, Git complains.

```
 git merge-file -p simple.ours.rb simple.common.rb simple.theirs.rb > simple.rb
 error: cannot merge binary files: simple.ours.rb
```

From reading [How to determine if Git handles a file as binary or as text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6119956/how-to-determine-if-git-handles-a-file-as-binary-or-as-text) I understand that Git is detecting the files as binary instead of text.

Apparently, Git assesses as binary any files that have a `NUL` byte in the first 8000 characters. I have opened each *.rb file in notepad2 and vim, though, and do not see any `NUL` bytes. The files simply contain the following (with slight diffs):

```
#! /usr/bin/env ruby

# print a greeting
def hello
  puts 'hello world'
end

hello()
```

Some Notes:

- I have repeatedly run both `dos2unix` and `unix2dos` on the `*.rb` files
- I am working on a Windows machine with Posh-Git

Why is Git assessing these files as binary? How can I fix this?

Comment: http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes

Comment: @user3159253 Thank you. I will peruse that.

Comment: Try `sed -i 's/\x0//g' simple.ours.rb`