# Which file types Git treats as binary by default?

Tags: git

I know how to force Git to treat e.g. JPEG file as binary using gitattributes but what is actually the default list of binary files for Git? Or is there any? I found what seems to be the system-wide gitattributes file on my system and this is its contents:

```
*.doc   diff=astextplain
*.DOC   diff=astextplain
*.docx  diff=astextplain
*.DOCX  diff=astextplain
*.dot   diff=astextplain
*.DOT   diff=astextplain
*.pdf   diff=astextplain
*.PDF   diff=astextplain
*.rtf   diff=astextplain
*.RTF   diff=astextplain
```

Does that mean that images are by default not treated as binary files?

EDIT: there could also theoretically be some "guessing" algorithm involved but I haven't found any details on it.

Comment: Good question! Did you see [this](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes) ?

Comment: Yes I have but I don't think it answers my question.

Comment: This is interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6134127/21728. Supposedly Git looks at first 8000 bytes and tries to find null byte in it. In our case, all the images contain null bytes there and Git still messes with their EOL conversion when the only rule we have in our .gitattributes is `* text=auto eol=lf`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no default list of binary files in git.

There is indeed a simple algorithm:

> If any of the first 8000 bytes contains a NULL Character, it is considered a binary.

You can read the exact code for this [here](https://github.com/git/git/blob/v2.43.0/xdiff-interface.c#L194-L200) for the latest git stable version as of this writing (2.43).

The shortest I could come up with to prove this:

```
$ git init
$ # A file with just a NULL character
$ echo -e '\x00' > bin 
$ # A file with just the ascii A character
$ echo -e 'A' > ascii 
$ # The last of 8000s first character is a NULL
$ (perl -e 'print "A" x 7999' ; echo -e "\x00") > long-bin 
$ # This one, the null is the 8001s character
$ (perl -e 'print "A" x 8000' ; echo -e "\x00") > long-ascii 
$ git commit --allow-empty --allow-empty-message
$ git stash -u
$ git stash show -u
git stash show -u
 ascii      |   1 +
 bin        | Bin 0 -> 2 bytes
 long-ascii |   1 +
 long-bin   | Bin 0 -> 8001 bytes
 4 files changed, 2 insertions(+))
```

Comment: Already answered as part of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6119956/how-to-determine-if-git-handles-a-file-as-binary-or-as-text