# Git/Github APK failure

Tags: android, git, github

I'm actually developing for Android. As I do changes, I make the app and send the apk file to my boss via dropbox. Lastly, I started sending it via its github file link. Since then apps won't install (I have my phone in Spanish, but I think in English the error says "Parse error").

It must be a Git/Github problem, because if I send the app via mail/dropbox or upload it to my phone by cable directly from my PC, it works perfectly.

First thing I thought was that the Git's Auto CRLF function, active by default in my PC, could be modifying the APK. But I uploaded the APK without this function and it still won't work.

So, what is causing this error that's driving me crazy?

Comment: Perhaps your APK is not treated as binary by git? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6119956/how-to-determine-if-git-handles-a-file-as-binary-or-as-text

Answer (score 1):

`autocrlf` would only influence the APK binary if said binary was tracked (git add/git commit)

But you don't have to track it: you can upload it as part of a release associated to a git tag in your GitHub repo. See "[Creating a release](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-releases/)".
This has the added benefit that you can tie a binary to an exact version (tag) of the sources.
And Git won't apply anything: "**[release](https://help.github.com/articles/about-releases/)**" is a notion entirely managed dby GitHub.