# Will adding attributes file increase Git performance?

Tags: git

Without `.gitattributes`, Git has to detect if a file is text or binary. If I add .gitattributes and specify the file is text, no detection is needed. I assume performance will increase a bit. Am I correct?

Comment: In general, correctness is much more of a concern than time with git. What scenario do you have that requires you to optimize?

Comment: @MadPhysicist not really, I'm just learning git and thought of this implication.

Comment: [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/80092/75264)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory, it could make lead to a slight performance boost. However, git only checks the first 8000 bytes of the file for null bytes ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6134127/2718801)), which would be quite fast.

So, sure, go for it! It's certainly not going to hurt, but you probably won't notice the difference unless you have a ridiculous number of files.